# How to setup a dependent dropdown list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need a dependent drop down list.

Normally categories and their list indexed by `=indirect(A1)` formula

But I need to select one list value then another drop down based on the first dropdown list.

Example;

```
Material. Size
Iron.     22*40
Iron.     31*34
Steel.    21*32 
Aluminum. 56*10
Rubber.   12*12
Rubber.   13*41
Rubber.   10*14
```

List 1 has multiple materials.

List 2 has sizes.

If I select one material , then need to show available size in another drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create Pivot table, by Below Gif.

Then Copy the Pivot Data To Each column

Named the the title as Material (Aluminum, Steel, Rubber)

Define the Name by selected column.

Then make Data validation list in A1 equal to Material

Then Enter This formula another cell to get result =indirect(A1)

@Erin Ding Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Pivot Table may be helpful to you.
[image]

Comment: This is good idea, I need to vlookup another dependent values based on the both selection. But here material list and their sizes grouped by pivot. So that, I need to select both values in data validation.